# mod_rewrite, only access one part of URL for blog entry

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In other sites I've worked on, I have been able to easily generate search engine friendly URLS using the following in .htaccess:

```
<files entry>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</files>
```

I'm working on a site hosted by a company that runs PHP as fast CGI and this does not work. I am trying to achieve the following URL - http://somewhere.com/blog/entry/12/this-is-the-title

I am just looking for the id (12 in the example) and do not necessarily need the title (my logic behind this being that the title might be changed by the client, links might be broken). I tried the following mod_rewrite but it does not work if I add the title:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^entry/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I've never worked with mod_rewrite before and a lot of the documentation I've come across is about achieving far more complex results. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .htaccess file is in fact placed as /blog/.htaccess, you will need a `RewriteBase /blog/` line.

Just looking for numbers will also help limit the returned id.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/entry/([01-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This also drops the '/?$' part of the regex. The '$' at the end anchors the match to the end of the string - you just need the numbers, and can ignore anything that is not a digit.

Comment: The .htaccess is in the blog directory, so it becomes `RewriteRule ^entry/([01-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]` This works until I try adding the title, for example http://somewhere.com/blog/entry/23 works, http://somewhere.com/blog/entry/23/the-title results in 404

Comment: drop the '/?$' part of the regex then. '$' anchors the match to the end of the string - you just need the numbers, and can ignore anything that is not a digit.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon.. when I went to actually implement this, with the correct filename of entry.php, it does not pass the `id`. Here is the .htaccess : `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^blog/entry/([01-9]+)/ entry.php?id=$1 [L]` Ideas? It seems to work if it points to index.php (passes the ID) - right now it goes to entry.php but without the ID

Comment: Okay, I tried this on another domain/host and it worked fine. Could it be something screwy with GoDaddy (the host in my question)?

Comment: To answer my own comment question, apparently. Dealing with GoDaddy support is a nightmare, I have no idea why the configuration did not work but I finally solved it by simply renaming "entry.php" to "article.php" and making the necessary change to .htaccess.